# Logic for ModelState.IsValid Empty If Block?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, modelstate

I've inherited an application with a code like below in the controller method. A coworker said it will behave as if that semicolon is not there (meaning that if the ModelState is valid, it will return the view) but it screams to me like a typo.

Is this some type of shortcut I am not aware of?  I tried to google and I cannot find any code that has a similar empty if block.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchRecord(SearchInfo searchInfo)
{
   . . .
   TryUpdateModel(searchInfo);

   If (ModelState.IsValid) ;  // There is a semicolon at the end of the line 

   return View(searchInfo);

   . . .
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything, it's pointless code.

Comment: Your co-worker is wrong. The semicolon makes the `if` an empty statement, and the view will always be returned - `if(1 == 2);  
Console.WriteLine("hello");` always prints "hello"

Comment: You could check it yousrself by debuging it line-by-line with a valid and an invalid ModelState